# How to groupby resultset with linq?

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that looks like this:

```
SELECT UrlId, TypeId, DomainId, Url, d.OrgId AS orgId
FROM SystemUrls
JOIN Domaindata d ON d.Id = DomainId
```

It gives me this result:

[image]

in the code this looks like:

[image]

**What I would like:**

is to group this result on the domainId 
so that I get two rows.

I have this class:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public long DomainId { get; set; }
    public List<SystemUrl> Urls { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to get a resul like :

> DomainId 79 Urls.count() = 2
>
> DomainId 81  Urls.COunt = 2

My attempt:

```
                var t =
                (from u in urls
                    select
                    new TestModel
                    {
                        DomainId = u.DomainId,
                        Urls = new List<SystemUrl> {new SystemUrl {Url = u.Url}}
                    }).GroupBy(v => v.DomainId).ToList();
```

the problem is that I seem to get the domainId right but none of the other data seems to follow:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var t = urls.GroupBy(u => u.DomainId)
    .Select(g => new TestModel{
        DomainId = g.Key,
        Urls = g.Select(u => new SystemUrl {Url = u.Url}).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: linq is not my strong side and at the moment I feel that i sould have been able to figure this out. Thanks

Comment: @Ra3IDeN - glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it:

```
var t = urls.GroupBy(v => v.DomainId).Select(g => new TestModel
{
     DomainId = g.Key,
     Urls = g.Select(u => new SystemUrl {Url = u.Url}).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! Linq is not my strong side and watching the two given answers I feel that I should have been able to figure this out but my thoughtprocess was a bit off.

Comment: You were quite close.

Answer (score 0):

Put DataAdapter reults into a datatable .  Then use following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;




namespace ConsoleApplication49
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Urld", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Typeid", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("DomainId", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 13, 1, 79 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 14, 2, 79 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 15, 2, 81 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 16, 1, 81 });

            var results = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("DomainID"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Count());

        }


    }

}
```